# changing rest endpoint with talend dynamically

Tags: rest, ip, port, talend, esb

So i'm working with talend esb 8 , in it i'm creating some rest end point .These endpoints will be used in an other software that needs these endpoint to be public (public ip) . So i find a solution to create a public ip fro my computer . the problem this solution gives me a single port but as you know each endpoint need a diffrent port.

Can you please suggest me a solution that will make the port of the end point variables so that it will change while the job running.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Talend Support about a similar problem ( you can't put a context variable as a REST endpoint neither). Talend did not give me any solution regarding this kind of issue. For our purpose we had to duplicate flows and deployed it 2 times with 2 different endpoints.
Other solution would be to have an API Manager acting as a proxy to redirect incoming requests to your service ?